# route does not work with javascript code in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, mern

I am trying to make routes for users if my user is available so user can stay at homepage and it is occurring this error (Uncaught Error: [Login] is not a `<Route>` component. All component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`)

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/homepage" element={<Homepage/>}>
      {
        user && user._id
          ? <Homepage/>
          : <Login/>
      }
    </Route>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
    <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to the way:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  < Routes>
    <Route path="/homepage" element={user && user.id ? <Homepage /> : <Login />}>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Homepage` and `Login` need to be rendered as the `element` of a `Route` since only `Route` or `React.Fragment` components can be children of the `Routes` component.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/homepage"
      element={user?._id ? <Homepage/> : <Login/>}
    />
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
    <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```